# System app reverts to original version after device reboot

Tags: android

I have created a custom System.img for my device, I need to put an APK as a system app, and I have places the app within /System/priv-app, app works flawlessly, I can download and install app updates from my own server, and after update is installed the correct version is used, until I reboot my device, and the version is reverted to the original app installed in Priv-App. I increment versionCode with every version and the issue is still present, what are my options? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As I turns out, it WAS the versionCode that prevented me from keeping updates around, I was changing the versionCode within the manifest, but gradle.build was overwriting it to the same versionCode back. I made sure build.gradle had the proper version and it allowed me to keep app updates after reboot.